# Simulate deterministic PDA with 1-tape Turing machine?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, pushdown-automata

Is it possible to write a 1-tape Turing machine in order to simulate a deterministic PDA? How would this be done?

Comment: 1-tape Turing machines can compute everything which is computable, and in particular any context-free language.

Comment: I understand that since all Turing machines can accept all languages by PDAs. I just need a description of how it can necessarily be done with just one tape.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. It's a programming exercise for Turing machines. You can interleave the stack and the input (either using separate cells or using a big enough alphabet). Or you can let the stack grow to the other side of the input. There are probably many other ways.